# JQuery insertAfter(); move the next table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table setup and when i hover my mouse over a table cell i want a info box shown next to the cell, im using Jquery insertAfter(); for this but the problem is that is moves the next cell wich he should not do because my info box is absolute position.

Fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DKZ/)

HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div#hover_info_box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$("table tr td").mouseover(function(){
    $('#hover_info_box').show().html("<p>content</p>").insertAfter(this);
});

$("table tr td").mouseout(function(){
    $('#hover_info_box').hide();
});
```

Comment: Would jQuery UI tooltip be something you could consider? http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [**adjusted fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DKZ/2/)

Namely, change your jQuery to:

```
$("table tr td").mouseover(function(){
    var td=$(this);
    $('#hover_info_box').show().html("<p>content</p>").css({left:td.position().left + td.outerWidth()+'px', top:td.position().top});
});

$("table tbody tr td").mouseout(function(){
    $('#hover_info_box').hide();
});
```

By using insertAfter you're breaking the flow of the document (leading to invalid HTML as much as the visual effect you note), all you need to do is correctly set the position of the information box relative to the cell currently being hovered over.

Comment: Is there also a option when i hover a cell at the end of a table the info box shows to the left of a table cell ?

Answer (score 2):

`insertAfter` breaks your markup, since `<div>` can't be inserted after `<td>` tag directly.

You may use `appendTo` instead and fix your CSS to display the info box at the right side of the cell.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/c9DKZ/4/

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, youre solution works, but when i move to the next cell i must exit the info box in order to get a new info box.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("table tr td").mouseover(function(){
    $('#hover_info_box').show().html("<p>content</p>").appendTo($(this).next());
});

$("table tr td").mouseout(function(){
    $('#hover_info_box').hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DKZ/3/)